# AEM/ CQ | Not able to acces Sling Servlet from Source outside AEM

Tags: aem

I have a SlingServlet which I am trying to access by making ajax call from html outside of AEM.At first it works but now I am getting following error:

> test.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:4502/bin/DamHandlerr.html?imgURL=http://s3.amazonaws.com/f…iles-aviary-prod-us-east-1/2016-05-24/3dfa830ede7b44c4a88e872b22875c85.png.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Can anyone guide me here?

Comment: This [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27985193/how-to-enable-cors-in-crxde-lite-aem) has a pointer to enable CORS in AEM using a custom Filter

Answer (score 0):

This type of request is called [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) (Cross Origin Resource Sharing). If you want the AJAX client host/port to call another host/port URL, the server needs to add appropriate headers in response to tell client that call to different host server is allowed.

You would need to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in response to allow AJAX client to successfully access the different origin URL.

Sometimes in modern browsers AJAX client, makes additional request to check if resource is safe to access called [Pre-flight Requests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing#Preflight_example), in that case additional headers would be needed in response as listed in the [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing#Preflight_example) and [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).